# Can't fast travel in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Whenever I try to fast travel, I can't because the guards are pursuing me. How do I make this stop? It's annoying when I'm trying to do quests at different parts of the map.

Comment: Are you asking why there is a message saying that guards are pursuing you? Sorry, but I can't really understand your question. "and it farkas"?

Comment: I edited your question. If it doesn't help, feel free to edit it again.

Answer (score 4):

By the sounds of it, you've committed a crime, and the guards are pursuing you. You could:

1. Give yourself in. (I.E. Go to jail)
2. Pay the fine.
3. Kill all witnesses (This will remove your bounty)

Answer (score -1):

If you know you didn't commit a crime, you might want to load your last save. I remember one of my times playing through fallout 3 whenever I walked into megaton they would all attack me and I ended up having to load an autosave.
Hope this helps!